# How to add this data to database in scraperwiki

Tags: python, pdf, screen-scraping, scraperwiki

```
import scraperwiki
import urllib2, lxml.etree
url = 'http://eci.nic.in/eci_main/statisticalreports/SE_1998/StatisticalReport-DEL98.pdf'
pdfdata = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
xmldata = scraperwiki.pdftoxml(pdfdata)
root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xmldata)
# how many pages in PDF
pages = list(root)
print "There are",len(pages),"pages"
#from page 86 to 107
for page in pages[86:107]:
    for el in page:
            data = {}
        if el.tag == "text":
            if int(el.attrib['left']) < 215: data = { 'Rank': el.text }
            elif int(el.attrib['left']) < 230: data['Name'] = el.text 
            elif int(el.attrib['left']) < 592: data['Sex'] = el.text
            elif int(el.attrib['left']) < 624: data['Party'] = el.text
            elif int(el.attrib['left']) < 750: data['Votes'] = el.text
            elif int(el.attrib['left']) < 801: data['Percentage'] = el.text
            print data
```

Now I am wondering how to save this data in the database in `scraperwiki`. I have tried a few commands like

```
scraperwiki.sqlite.save(unique_keys=[], table_name='ecidata1998', data=data)
```

but they dont give me the required result when I check the dataset, Is there something wrong with the code or the last statement. Please help. New at Python programming and Scraperwiki.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

First, the conditions you've set to pull different content from the PDF need to be made more restricted and precise (e.g. `if int(el.attrib['left']) < 215` will pull any text that has a left position of less than 215 pixels, which applies to other content in the PDF pages you're looking at, e.g. the text "Constituency").

Second, you need a way to check when you have all the data for that row and can move on to the next one. (You could try and pull the data out by rows, but I just found it easier to grab data from each field in turn and make a new row when I had all the data for that row.)

(As to why `scraperwiki.sqlite.save` wasn't working, it's probably because you had rows of empty values in there, but your data as you had it wasn't correct anyway.)

This works for me:

```
import scraperwiki
import urllib2
import lxml.etree


def create_blank_row():
    """ Create an empty candidate data dictionary. """
    return {'Rank': None,
            'Name': None,
            'Sex': None,
            'Party': None,
            'Votes': None,
            'Percentage': None}


def row_is_filled(dictionary):
    """ Return True if all values of dictionary are filled; False if not. """
    for item in dictionary.values():
        if not item:
            return False
    return True


def main():
    url = ('http://eci.nic.in/eci_main/statisticalreports'
           '/SE_1998/StatisticalReport-DEL98.pdf')
    pdfdata = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    xmldata = scraperwiki.pdftoxml(pdfdata)
    root = lxml.etree.fromstring(xmldata)

    # how many pages in PDF
    pages = list(root)
    print "There are", len(pages), "pages"

    output_data = []
    candidate_data = create_blank_row()
    #from page 86 to 107
    for page in pages[86:107]:
        for el in page:
            if el.tag == "text":
                if 206 < int(el.attrib['left']) <= 214:
                    # There are some None values here which we want to ignore.
                    if el.text:
                        candidate_data['Rank'] = el.text

                if int(el.attrib['left']) == 222:
                    # Also removes ". " from start of names.
                    candidate_data['Name'] = el.text[2:]

                if int(el.attrib['left']) == 591:
                    candidate_data['Sex'] = el.text

                if int(el.attrib['left']) == 622:
                    candidate_data['Party'] = el.text

                if 725 < int(el.attrib['left']) <= 753:
                    candidate_data['Votes'] = el.text

                if 790 < int(el.attrib['left']) < 801:
                    candidate_data['Percentage'] = el.text

            if row_is_filled(candidate_data):
                output_data.append(candidate_data)
                candidate_data = create_blank_row()

    # Collect candidate data into a list then add to SQL database.
    # Calls to this SQL write function slow, so minimise how many times we do.
    scraperwiki.sqlite.save(unique_keys=['Rank', 'Name', 'Sex', 'Party', 
                                         'Votes'], 
                            table_name='ecidata1998',
                            data=output_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```